# What is a "Partial Matching Index"?

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, foreign-key

I'm trying to learn more about the "foreign key references check" query plan operator introduced in SQL Server 2016. There's not a lot of information about it out there. Microsoft announced it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/05/23/query-optimizer-additions-in-sql-server/) and I blogged about it [here](https://orderbyselectnull.com/2017/12/05/the-referential-integrity-operator/). The new operator can be seen by deleting a row from a parent table with 254 or more incoming foreign key references: [dbfiddle link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f2d647f14b46521c5bab1b61a93b8f2c).

There are three different counts displayed in the operator details:

[image: FK check details]

- **Foreign Key References Count** is the number of incoming foreign keys.
- **No matching Indexes Count** is the number of incoming foreign keys without a suitable index. Verifying that the updated or deleted table won't violate that constraint will require a scan of a child table.
- I don't know what **Partial Matching Indexes Count** represents.

What is a partial matching index in this context? I wasn't able to get any of the following to work:

- Filtered indexes
- Putting the foreign key column as an `INCLUDE` column for an index
- Indexes with the foreign key column as the second key column
- Single column indexes for multiple column foreign keys
- Creating multiple covering indexes to enable an "index join" plan for a multiple column foreign key

[Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman) pointed out that multiple column foreign keys can match indexes even if the index keys are in a different order than the foreign key columns. His code is [here](https://pastebin.com/7XAtVH6R) in case someone is able to use it as as starting point to figure out more about partial matching indexes.

Answer (score 13):

I spoke to people much smarter than I and we will be documenting this soon™.

The actual definition of this, in the interim is:

> PartialMatchingIndexCount reflects the number of references that could
>   be checked using index seeks, but the index key does not cover all the
>   columns being checked. For example, the corresponding
>   ForeignKeyReferenceCheck elements contain both a Seek Predicates and a
>   Predicate element.

In addition:

> If this number is greater than 0, there is a potential performance issue, in case the partial matches result in large numbers of rows.

Comment: A working example or actual documentation would be glorious. Bounty offered

Answer (score 3):

After some more googling, I managed to come up with a post that mentions "Partial Matching Indexes" and Foreign Keys

The [March 1, 2013 Blog Post in Carlos Klapp's Code Blog entitled `Foreign Keys without Indexes`](http://carlosklapp.blogspot.com/2013/03/foreign-keys-without-indexes.html) has the Stored Procedure called `Util_FKsWithoutIndexes` which looks for foreign keys that does not have proper indexes for FK relationships. (Looks like this blogger lifted this from [SQL Server Central's `The Ultimate Index-Less Foreign-Key Finder` (Oct 15, 2009)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Administration/68357/)) The blog says the following:

> Searches for foreign key constraints that don't have fully matching indexes.
>
> The best partial matching indexes are outputted with MatchCounts and column comparisons
>
> Generates a CREATE INDEX template for each foreign-key with no matching index or a partial-matching index.
>
> Customize as needed (add includes, if you want it clustered, or if it should be a part of the primary key, or if you want to merge with another index)
>
> FKs missing full matching indexes can severely hurt the performance of DELETES on the referenced table due to table-scans for checking referential integrity,
>    as well as SELECTS on the referencing tables where the foreign-key column(s) are in the WHERE or JOIN predicates (This will affect you whether a constraint exists or not).
>   This only checks the first N columns of the index where N is the number of columns in the foreign key constraint.
>
> Index column order is not verified beyond this (A two-col FK that has 1 matching column in the 2nd col of a 3-col index will be outputted as a partial match)
>
> If your database has no foreign key constraints, then this tool will be worthless to you.
>
> Many databases have partial foreign key constraint coverage. This only works on related tables where constraints are declared.

If I understand this correctly, if a FK relationship does not have an index that matches every column in some needed index, there may be some indexes that have some of the columns. For example, if a FK relationship has three columns (`a`,`b`,`c`) but there is no index with those same three columns, there may exist an index that has (`a`,`b`) or (`a`,`c`) or (`b`,`c`) and may help with queries but will require some index scans to rows with the missing column.

If there are no indexes at all that can support a FK constraint, then the "Partial Matching Indexes Count" will be zero(`0`), or at least will not increment this count.

Comment: Is this what you had in mind? Still can't get it to work... http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b32851513d666fe487722701727b5674

Comment: Not exactly. Try making a FK with `(FKey2,FKey3)` and create an index on `FKey2`. Please try that.

Comment: Please remember I am not a SQL Server guy, but I am just trying to help.

Comment: I understand and appreciate any ideas to try. I also can't get the two column one to work.

Comment: You could ditch `create unique index FULL_IX_UNIQUE ON FK_PARENT_TABLE (FKey, Fkey2, Fkey3)`, keep the index on `FKey2` and try again.